# Internet Explorer 8 error - Expected Identifier, string or number on blank line - JQuery

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I keep getting an "Expected identifier" error on line 103. I know it is probably a misplaced coma or semicolon but I can't seem to see it.

```
$('select').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var numberOfOptions = $this.children('option').length;

            $this.addClass('sHidden');
            $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');
            $this.after('<div class="selectStyled"></div>');
            var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.selectStyled');

            $styledSelect.append('<div class="select">' + $this.children('option').eq(0).text() + '</div>');

            var $list = $("<ul/>").addClass('options');

            $styledSelect.append($list); <-- Line 102 so the error is on the next line.
```

Comment: Try: `var $list = $('<ul/>')...`. Notice the self closing tag.

Comment: `$list = $("<ul>").css('class', 'options');` looks awkward; you might want to check what you actually wanted to do there...

Comment: elclanrs - still the same error.

Comment: If `$styledSelect.append($list);` is line 102 and the error is on the next line ... why don't you show line 103 then??

Comment: Because line 103 is blank.